# Get client IP inside Middleware Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, middleware

Can anyone help me. I want to know if there is any way to get the client IP in a middleware that I created.

I've tried:

```
env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

and none of these returns nothing.

I have already entered my middleware after them all:

in my application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch :: Head, "MyMiddleware".
```

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**request.env**

```
request.env
=> {"GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1",
 "PATH_INFO"=>"/events/1",
 "QUERY_STRING"=>"",
 "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1",
 "REMOTE_HOST"=>"127.0.0.1",
 "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
 "REQUEST_URI"=>"http://localhost:3000/events/1",
 "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
 "SERVER_NAME"=>"localhost",
 "SERVER_PORT"=>"3000",
 "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1",
 "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-09-17)",
 "HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000",
 "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0",
 "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
 "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.5",
 "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate",
 "HTTP_DNT"=>"1",
 "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"nameofapp-example_session=Qnh5ZMQVN5V2821f",
 "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"keep-alive",
 "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"=>"max-age=0",
...
```

Each of these are keys you can use.  In your case it would be one of these two

```
request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
request.env["REMOTE_HOST"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this keys dont work in localhost. I think there's no way. But thanks.